# Why does StockWatcher.java use class variables instead of local variables in onModuleLoad?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

So, yeah. That. I'm going through the tutorial one step at a time, so if the answer comes up later, forgive me. It's step 1 in [this section](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/buildui#implement).

I understand the ease of using this to have access in other methods in the EntryPoint class, but coming from the Spring MVC world, this sort of thing might be thought of as a controller and be a singleton (bean). Is it wrong to think this way in the GWT world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GWT you are coding as if it was a desktop AWT program. So, you do not have CDI or anything similar.

So, if you put all your information in a bean, you still would have to either:

- keep a bean attribute in the class
- pass it as a parameter in the method call

to get a reference to it (instead of retrieving it from CDI when needed)

While you can still use a bean when needed, these attributes are closely linked to the main class (in fact they are other graphical components to show). In general, I would only use bean when you have a bunch of attributes that are tightly coupled between them but are not tightly coupled to any other class.